JavaFX, scrollpane that's always white
I'm creating this messager app that looks like Telegram. I've added BorderPane and made a chatList on the left of it using LeftRegion and LeftStackPane.
I want that every time you click a chat (username), you are redirected to a chat with this user. So, in the middle of my BorderPane I made a nice background like Telegram does have. However, I realised that I need to use scrollpane.
I need to use ScrollPane to be able to view all the messages if there are many.
So I added it, and it's just white.
I tried to make it transparent and everything but it doesn't work that way.
How can I make my scrollpane either turn tranpsarable in relation to BorderPane background, or somehow change ScrollPane background so it's not always white, but some other colour or even maybe an image.
ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(messageList);

// Create a new ScrollPane
scrollPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #00000; " + // Background color
        "-fx-border-color: #000000; " + // Border color
        "-fx-border-radius: 0px; " + // Border radius
        "-fx-background-radius: 0px;"); // Background radius

// Set the CSS style of the ScrollPane's viewport
scrollPane.viewportBoundsProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    scrollPane.setClip(new Rectangle(newValue.getWidth(), newValue.getHeight()));
});

scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);  // Ensures the scroll pane width fits the content
scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);
scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);  // Ensures the scroll pane width fits the content
scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);

scrollPane.setVisible(true);

//StackPane for INFOBOX and MESSAGE LIST
StackPane centerPane = new StackPane();
centerPane.getChildren().add(scrollPane);
centerPane.getChildren().add(infoBox);

Here's image before adding ScrollPanea



What kind of Node is the variable messageList, in the code in your question? Is it a TextArea or a ListView ?

For a chat application, I advise using a ListView instead of a ScrollPane
You probably don't want a ScrollPane at all.
Instead, you probably want a transparent ListView:

How to get transparent list view in javafx?

That way you can add messages to the list and let the list view handle scrolling.
Example CSS and layout, using a ListView
Here is a translucent ListView with styled cells and a static repeating background image.
Styling is just for demo purposes, you can study the example to understand how something like this might be done and apply your own styling and implementation, with or without FXML.
styled-list.css
.root {
    -fx-font-size: 20px;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

.list-background {
    -fx-background-image:url(dragon.png);
    -fx-background-size: 256px;
    -fx-opacity: 10%;
}

.list-cell {
    -fx-background-color: rgba(144,238,144,.1);
    -fx-text-fill: indigo;
}

.list-cell:odd {
    -fx-background-color: rgba(32,178,170,.1);
    -fx-border-color: rgba(32,178,170,.2);
    -fx-border-width: 1 0 1 0;
}

.list-view {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

styled-list.fxml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>

<StackPane stylesheets="@styled-list.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <StackPane styleClass="list-background" />
      <ListView />
   </children>
</StackPane>

Image generated using Scene Builder's View | Show Sample Data function:

Image resource with attribution
The example icon used for styling, with required attribution is:
<a href="https://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/dragon" title="dragon icons">Dragon icons created by Icongeek26 - Flaticon</a>


Additional Styling
For a chat application, you probably want different styles applied for sent and received messages. Info on how to accomplish that is in:

JavaFx ListView for chat application

